# How to extract values from nested dict with python

Tags: python, dictionary, nested

here is my data :

```
[{'_index': 'script1',
  '_id': '123456',
  '_source': {'data_version': '20220701',
              'SD_RESOURCE_TYPE': 'PDE',
              'SD_RESOURCE_SIZE': 'UNIQUE'}},
 {'_index': 'script11',
  '_id': '123457',
  '_source': {'data_version': '20220701',
              'SD_RESOURCE_TYPE': 'CPS',
              'SD_RESOURCE_SIZE': 'CLUSTER'}},
 {'_index': 'script111',
  '_id': '123458',
  '_source': {'data_version': '20220701',
              'SD_RESOURCE_TYPE': 'HIGH',
              'SD_RESOURCE_SIZE': 'CLUSTER'}}]
```

My goal is to extract values from fields `_source` and put them into a dict named `fields`.

Here is my code :

```
fields = {}
for num, doc in enumerate(elastic_docs):
    source_data = doc["_source"]
```

Unfortunatly, I do not have my hope return.

I want this return :

```
{'data_version': '20220701'  '20220701' '20220701',
 'SD_RESOURCE_TYPE': 'PDE' 'CPS' 'HIGH' ,
 'SD_RESOURCE_SIZE': 'UNIQUE' 'UNIQUE' 'CLUSTER'}
```

Maybe you can help. Thanks

Comment: What do you need help with exactly? This is a good start, but you need to do something with `source_data`. BTW, `num` is unused, so no point doing `enumerate()` here.

Comment: For reference, this advice: *"**Make a good faith attempt to solve the problem yourself first.** Users here respond negatively if your question gives them the impression that you're asking them to do your work for you. On the other hand, questions that ask about a specific issue that you're having a problem with usually receive a much better response. **Ask about specific problems with your existing implementation.** If you can't do that yet, try some more of your own work first or searching for more general help"* -- [Asking about homework](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822)

Answer (score 1):

You can build a dict containing the data you want as follows:

```
from collections import defaultdict

fields = defaultdict(list)
for entry in elastic_docs:
    for field, value in entry['_source'].items():
        fields[field].append(value)
  
print(fields)
```

Output:

```
{
 'data_version': ['20220701', '20220701', '20220701'],
 'SD_RESOURCE_TYPE': ['PDE', 'CPS', 'HIGH'],
 'SD_RESOURCE_SIZE': ['UNIQUE', 'CLUSTER', 'CLUSTER']
}
```